# Previous month in parameter

Tags: date, reporting-services, parameters

I need to set a Hidden Default Parameter in SSRS.

In my query I need to *not* show last months total but the month before that, ie in Feb I need to show  Dec totals.

I usually use this for last month but cannot tweak it for the month prior.

Set first date of last month:

```
=DateAdd("m", -1, DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), 1))
```

Set last date of last month:

```
=DateAdd("d", -1, DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), 1))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i understand you right you want to:

Get the first day of two months from now

```
=DateAdd("m", -2, DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), 1))
```

And you want to get the last day on month two months from now

```
=DateAdd("d" , -1 , DateAdd("m", -1, DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), 1)))
```

Comment: what about the last day on month 13 months ago ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly what you need, use something like:

```
DateAdd
(
    DateInterval.Month
    , -1
    , DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, DateSerial(Year(Parameters!Date.Value), Month(Parameters!Date.Value), 1))
)
```

Used in a report:

[image]